# How to Change the default blue color background of Android Wear notification

Tags: android, wear-os

I would like to change the default blue background of the android notification.

My icon doesn't go well with blue and I want to change it.
Is there any method to specify the color of the background?

[image]

Comment: It looks just fine :/

Comment: I just gave an example there. Here is the original one of mine.
https://dl.pushbulletusercontent.com/HBT3b6T4HUgUWulFr2MAfsu2qn0WJ883/screen.png

Answer (score 0):

you can't. Neither the background of the Action nor the background of the default wearable notification card can be changed, with the current sdk. And imo it will not be never possible

Comment: If we are talking about the background color of the blue circle, there is no way

Comment: I think you are right. I tried xml too. It didn't work. I will accept the answer if no one comes with a solution in next few days.